# differences between subsetting POSIXlt and POSIXct in R

Tags: r, timestamp, posixct, subset, posixlt

DATA

```
v1 <- c("2015-01-05 15:00:00", "2015-01-05 15:45:00", "2015-01-05 15:00:30")
```

OPERATIONS

```
v2 <- strptime(v1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
str(v2)
POSIXlt[1:3], format: "2015-01-05 15:00:00" "2015-01-05 15:45:00" "2015-01-05 15:00:30"

v3 <- v2[!v2$min]  # create v3 from v2 eliminating min != 00
```

RESULT (successful subsetting)

```
str(v3)
POSIXlt[1:2], format: "2015-01-05 15:00:00" "2015-01-05 15:00:30"
```

Now creating v4 by coercing v2 to POSIXct (successful)

```
v4 <- as.POSIXct(v2, format = "%y/%m/%d  %H:%M")

str(v4)
POSIXct[1:3], format: "2015-01-05 15:00:00" "2015-01-05 15:45:00" "2015-01-05 15:00:30"
```

OPERATION IN QUESTION - Applying the same subsetting operation to POSIXct as to POSIXlt causes the error below

```
v5 <- v4[!v4$min]  # reassign v2 eliminating min != 00
```

RESULT (error)

```
  Error in v4$min : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

QUESTIONS:
a) Why this difference in behavior?
b) What would be an equivalent operation to use with POSIXct?
Many thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You misunderstand a critical difference between `POSIXlt` and `POSIXct`:

- `POSIXlt` is a 'list type' with components you can access as you do
- `POSIXct` is a 'compact type' that is essentially just a number

You almost always want `POSIXct` for comparison and effective storage (eg in a `data.frame`, or to index a `zoo` or `xts` object with) and can use `POSIXlt` to access components.  Be warned, though, that the components follow C library standards so e.g. the current years is 115 (as you always need to add 1900), weekdays start at zero etc pp.

Doing `str()` or `unclass` on these is illuminating.  For historical reasons, `strptime()` returns a `POSIXlt`. I wish it would return a `POSIXct`.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. I've been finding it easier to coerce to POSIXlt (via strptime()) and then to POSIXct (via as.POSIXct()). Goal is to create xts object.

Comment: Yes accessing part of time via conversion seems natural, eg from [lubridate](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/blob/master/R/accessors-minute.r)  `minute.default <- function(x) as.POSIXlt(x, tz = tz(x))$min`

Comment: @jaimedash If you know what you're doing with base R there is no need for lubridate.

Comment: +1 I didn't mean to imply otherwise. Though my comment wasn't that clear, I intended it to show how lubridate _uses_ base R `as.POSIXlt` to access (or subset in OP's terminology) parts of `POSIXct` objects